# can't get a form to show on a page

Tags: html, forms

I am trying to implement a basic contact form but can't get the labels and the inputs to show. Here is the code:

```
    <div id="contact">
        <form method="post" action="something.php">
            <div>
                <label for="address">Your email address:</label>
                <input name="address" type="text" id="address"/>                            
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="query">What is your query?</label>
                <input name="query" type="text" id="address"/>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT"/>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

If I put this on a page by itself it shows like it it supposed to. However, on my page it doesn't.

I unhide #contact using a jQuery .show() function.
And it is placed within another div that has a background image.

Is there anything in the last that is incorrect?

the actual form is showing. But the inside div's, labels and inputs don't.

the jQuery code looks like this:

```
function displayBlock(id, hide1, hide2, hide3, hide4) {
    $('#content_boxes #content_bg '+ hide1).hide();
    $('#content_boxes #content_bg '+ hide2).hide();
    $('#content_boxes #content_bg '+ hide3).hide();
    $('#content_boxes #content_bg '+ hide4).hide();
    $('#content_boxes #content_bg '+ id).show();
}
```

The function is being called by onclick events via the navigation bar:

```
<div id="header">

    <div id="navigation">

        <div id="site_logo" onclick="displayBlock('#welcome', '#about', '#albums', '#media', '#contact')">
            <a href="#"><img src="images/logo_website.png"></a>
        </div>

        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li onclick="displayBlock('#about', '#welcome', '#albums', '#media', '#contact')"><a href = "#">ABOUT</a></li>
                <li onclick="displayBlock('#albums', '#welcome','#about', '#media', '#contact')"><a href = "#">ALBUMS</a></li>
                <li onclick="displayBlock('#media', '#welcome', '#about', '#albums', '#contact')"><a href = "#">MEDIA</a></li>
                <li onclick="displayBlock('#contact', '#welcome', '#about', '#albums', '#media')"><a href = "#">CONTACT</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

    </div>

</div>
```

It's for a personal website just to show music that I record

Comment: Post your js code. You have to put in the for attr in labels th id of ithe input, and you have the same id address two times, that should be the error with your js. The id should be unique

Comment: the id was a mistake but still doesn't work

Comment: How are you calling the function, what parameters are you passing?

Comment: You can do an http://jsfiddle.net and share here the link to review

Comment: here is a fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/cjWpT/ - i can see the form on this but not my page